# Python Assign a list to numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to assign a range of number to a list of employees at random.

So for example I have employees John, Rick, Sally, Bill and they need to be assigned number 1 through 26 at random.

So John could have 1,3,20,15 assigned to him
Rick could have 5,10,26, assigned, etc etc.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from random import shuffle
number = 26
emp = list('John', 'Sally', 'Rick', 'Bill')
shuffle(emp)

#then get stuck on how to loop through this properly
```

Not much, I know. Any help or general direction is appreciated.

Comment: whats your desired output?

Comment: So, you want to distribute the numbers 1..26 randomly to 4 people, so each number is only assigned once and all numbers are assigned to somebody…? Make a list of 1..26, shuffle it, assign it in chunks (number of numbers divided by number of people…).

Comment: please check my updated answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you want to randomly distribute the numbers between employees where all the numbers are to be distributed and each employee has multiple numbers.

One solution is to use one list per employee. However, to make it easy to programmatically choose between the employees and adjust the program to a different number of employees, I have put all the lists into dictionary.

Note that instead of `list(1, 2, 3)`, I am using the syntax `[1, 2, 3]` as this syntax for constructing lists is more common.

```
# choice picks a random element from a list
from random import choice 

# emp_numbers is the collection of lists, one for each employee
emp_numbers = {'John':[], 'Sally':[], 'Rick':[], 'Bill':[]};

# emp is constructed from emp_numbers
# so that we don't have to list out the employees twice.
# We can't use emp_numbers.keys() directly as an input to choice because 
# emp_numbers.keys() doesn't support indexing since .keys() doesn't
# return a list. Choice requires indexing to function.
# Thus we convert it into a list, which does support indexing.
#
# (If you are still using python 2, then keys() does return a list,
# but converting a list to a list is harmless, so our code runs in both versions)
emp = list(emp_numbers.keys())

# now we want to distribute the numbers
numbers = 26;

for number in range(1, 26+1):
   #for each number, pick an employee.
   employee_name = choice(emp);
   #append the number to the end of that employee's list of numbers
   emp_numbers[employee_name].append(number)

print(emp_numbers)
```

This prints something like: `{'Rick': [4, 12, 21, 22, 24], 'John': [1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 17, 25, 26], 'Sally': [2, 7, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 23], 'Bill': [3]}`
`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign only one number to each name. You can use `random.randint` to generate random number between `0` and `26` and simple use list comprehension to assign numbers to each user as tuple,

```
import random
number = 26
emp = ['John', 'Sally', 'Rick', 'Bill']

x = [(i,random.randint(0,number+1)) for i in emp]
print(x)

# output,
[('John', 26), ('Sally', 8), ('Rick', 2), ('Bill', 19)]
```

If you want to generate more than one number for each employee you can use `random.sample`,

```
import random
number = 26
number_to_generate = 3 # to generate 3 random numbers for each emp
emp = ['John', 'Sally', 'Rick', 'Bill']

x = [(i,*random.sample(range(0, number+1), number_to_generate)) for i in emp]
print(x)

# output,
[('John', 4, 3, 21), ('Sally', 3, 24, 7), ('Rick', 12, 4, 2), ('Bill', 17, 19, 11)]
```

Or as a dictionary,

```
x = {i:random.sample(range(0, number+1), number_to_generate) for i in emp}
print(x)

# output,
{'John': [17, 25, 11], 'Sally': [5, 7, 8], 'Rick': [11, 4, 21], 'Bill': [10, 3, 5]}
```